# How does mmap'ed data work with object allocation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, mmap, virtual-memory

Im a little confused on how `mmap()` works with the frameworks on iOS or OSX.

If a file is mapped to virtual memory using `mmap()` and data is requested from it, the the kernel pages in the data to RAM. How does this actually affect how one creates objects?

If one usually creates an object using `alloc`/`init`, the memory block is allocated and the object initiated. But what if the data resides in virtual memory, in a `mmap`'ed file? Does the `alloc` need to be called on the object? Does the allocated memory for the object get filled with the data from virtual memory? Or does one skip the `alloc` call and just pass in the pointer to the data in virtual memory?

e.g. an image or a sound file, if I know where the file is in virtual memory, how would I setup the object?

If one allocates the data, doesn't it get duplicated if the data is already paged into RAM?

I was thinking that using memory from virtual addresses would remove the need to allocate on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one object you are storing in the mmaped space, then you simply skip the alloc and use the location directly.  However, normally you will have more than one object, and now you are into managing it yourself.  Typically at least some portion of it will be laid out in a fixed manner, so that both processes know where to find things.  Instead of pointers you get the fun of using offsets from the start of the arena, since that works in both processes' address space.

In essence, you're given a chunk of memory, as if you'd done one big malloc/alloc and you get to play around within it.

If you have, say

```
void *p = mmap( <appropriate arguments> );
```

and you want to put an object of type foo at offset 200, you would say

```
foo *f = (foo *)p+200;
```

and now you can manipulate f in all the normal ways, subject to f not containing any pointers into the mmapped space.   It is generally good discipline to substitute offsets for such pointers, and then when you need to follow one, you can convert it to a pointer (by adding p).

Comment: Yes, offsets will be used, I just wanted to confirm if alloc can be skipped if the offset is known and the correct data is treated as an object. e.g UIImage, calling init on the known data that was mmap'ed

Comment: Confirmed.  Once you know the offset, you can cast a pointer to that location to a pointer to your object type and you're off and running.

Comment: Ok cool thanks. So how does the vm data get accessed? Does one pass the offset and size of the known data? Taking the UIImage example, if offset 500 is known to be an image and it is a certain size, how do we tell the system to only take a certain amount of data and process it as the image?

Comment: I elaborated my answer.  Hope that helps.  If it is an image, or something that might have varying size, you need to keep from wandering off the end in the same way as if it were allocated regularly.

Comment: With regard to using mmap in iOS... So you have to use offsets if you have multiple mmap objects, but is it possible to have a separate mmap object per Class, or would they all reference the same virtual memory address space?

Comment: Just gave it a try myself using some ivars in separate classes and it seems to work just fine, cool.